# Montfortian Consecration to the Virgin Mary and Prayers with Requests?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, virgin-mary

I am consecrated to the Virgin Mary through Saint Louis Marie Grignion de Montfort's method. Although I have read his treatise on the matter, I find myself in a situation that I hadn't considered when reading his work. If you are familiar with the treatise, you know that all the merits of our prayers are given to Mother Mary so that she can present them to God "more perfectly." Therefore, you don't ask for anything in your prayers; rather, you simply ask for the Virgin Mary's intercession.

But what should one do with prayers that have a specific part for asking for something? For example, I have many cards/icons with prayers and images of saints, and one specific example is Saint John Paul II's prayer where, at the end, you can ask for something you need and possibly receive it through the saint's intercession. Another example is Saint Thomas Aquinas's prayer asking for intelligence.

So, what should someone consecrated to the Virgin Mary do with prayers like these? Omit the parts where you ask for something (but, in the case of Saint Thomas Aquinas's prayer, the entire prayer is a request) or just ask anyway?

If there's anything I have not understood properly about the consecration or about praying, please, correct me.

Comment: This might be a question better suited to ask a spiritual advisor, but I can offer one point of reason. There are clearly prayers in the breviary that are about the same as what are on the holy cards you're referring to and the necessity of pray those prayers is not abrogated for priests and religious who are consecrated to Mary by any formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Montfortian Consecration to the Virgin Mary and Prayers with Requests?**

Your consecration to Mary allows you to say these other prayers and petitions. Keep in mind that you do everything through, with, in and for Mary for the sake of Jesus. Both of you desire you to grow. In praying to St. Thomas for the greater intellectual ability is permitted as by being consecrated to Mary, your initiatives are equally consecrated to her, even if aided by other saints. There is no jealousy amongst the saints.

Through the consecration to Mary all your efforts and desires are hers, even when the petitions of help are from other saint of patron saint are her too. Be a peace with what you are doing. Mary is there beside you!

Likewise, do not forget to pray to Guardian Angel everyday!

Comment: Thank you a lot. This really helped me to put my prayers in order. I just didn't understand properly what "your [...] desires are hers" mean.